how to fix AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items' when create new user
I have some classes and their relationship like this
class Account(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    create_day = Column(Date, default=date.today)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    user = relationship("User", backref="account", uselist=False)  # Thiết lập quan hệ 1-1
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name


class User(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String(50))
    birth_day = Column(Date)
    email = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    phone_numbers = relationship('PhoneNumber',backref='user',  lazy=True)
    
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    role = Column(String(50), nullable=False, default="user")  
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',  
        'polymorphic_on': role          
    }
    

class Doctor(User):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    specialty = Column(String(100), nullable=True) 
    degree = Column(String(100), nullable=True)  
    experience = Column(String(100),nullable=True)
    current_workplace = Column(String(100),nullable=True)
    exam_dates = relationship('ExamSchedule', backref='doctor', lazy=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'doctor',  
    }

class Nurse(User):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'nurse',  
    }

class Patient(User):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    insurance_number = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'patient',  
    }
    

class Admin(User):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'admin',  
    }

class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique = True)
    type_number = Column(String(50), nullable=False ,default="personal")
    # user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

this is my file admin.py:
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from app.models import  User, PhoneNumber
from app.extensions import db

def init_admin(app):
    admin = Admin(app, name="Admin Panel", template_mode="bootstrap4")
    admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
    admin.add_view(ModelView(PhoneNumber, db.session))


init.py:
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from app.admin import init_admin
from config import Config
from app.extensions import db,migrate, login_manager
from app.models import *


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    init_admin(app)
    Config.init_cloudinary()
    return app

requirements.txt:
alembic==1.14.0
blinker==1.8.2
certifi==2024.8.30
click==8.1.7
cloudinary==1.41.0
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.3
Flask-Admin==1.6.1
Flask-Login==0.6.3
Flask-Migrate==4.0.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.2
greenlet==3.1.1
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
Mako==1.3.6
MarkupSafe==3.0.2
PyMySQL==1.1.1
python-dotenv==1.0.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.36
typing_extensions==4.12.2
urllib3==2.2.3
Werkzeug==3.1.2
WTForms==3.2.1

Why is the Phone Numbers field not displayed when I go to the admin/User page?
and when i press create or edit button it shows this error : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
how to fix the error?

It looks like you missed a ')' at the end of admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session)

sorry, I copied it wrong

Maybe a little bit more code would be better, I can't find which object call the attribute 'items'

probably this https://stackoverflow.com/a/79221350/12502959

I noticed you edited your question to show the versions, which only increases the possibility that the answer I linked is what you need, any reason you haven't tried that yet?

i tried, i also have WTForms==3.2.1 but it still has that error

the issue is with 3.2.1, you have to use a different version. can you test with 3.1.2?

oh it worked. thank you sm
